# Configuring Nginx Reverse Proxy for HTTP and HTTPS Redirects with Docker Containers

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm wondering if it's possible to deploy two containers (a Docker container on port 4041 and an Nginx container on port 8081) to set up a reverse proxy. I would like this reverse proxy to redirect requests from "domain.com:4041" to "domain.com:8081" using HTTP and requests from "domain.com:4042" to "domain.com:8082" using HTTPS.

Here's a diagram to illustrate my idea:

[image: diagram]

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this with Docker and Nginx? Thank you in advance for your help!

PS: If you have a better way to configure HTTPS with Docker, I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, Nginx cannot perform this task, especially not in conjunction with Docker, unless a specific path is specified, like "domain.com/service".

For exemple:

```
domain.com:8080 --> change to domain.com/service
```

The folder should be like this:

```
.
├── certs
│   ├── ssl_certificate.crt
│   └── ssl_certificate.key
├── conf.d
│   └── domain.com.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
└── html
    ├── 404.html
    ├── 50x.html
    └── index.html
```

Here is my Docker Compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: webserver
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d/domain.com.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - ./html:/etc/nginx/html
...
# other services
```

And here is the corresponding Nginx configuration file located at conf.d/domain.com.conf:

```yaml
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
                root /etc/nginx/html;
                index index.html;
        }
        location /service/ {
                proxy_pass http://ip:port/;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_certificate.key;

        location / {
                root /etc/nginx/html;
                index index.html;
        }
        location /service/ {
                proxy_pass http://ip:port/;
        }
}
```

In the certs directory, the following SSL certificate files are present:

ssl_certificate.crt
ssl_certificate.key
These keys were generated using OpenSSL.

```bash
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout ssl_certificate.key -out ssl_certificate.crt -days 1825 -nodes -subj "/CN=domain.com"
```